# Tic Tac Toe in Ada

Tags: beginner, ada

I'm new in Ada and made the following Tic Tac Toe implementation. It works as intended.

### tictactoe.gpr

```
project TicTacToe is

    for Source_Dirs use ("src/**");
    for Object_Dir use "obj";
    for Exec_Dir use ".";
    for Main use ("main.adb");

    for Create_Missing_Dirs use "True";

    package Compiler is
        for Default_Switches ("Ada") use ("-g");
    end Compiler;

end TicTacToe;
```

### src/main.adb

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Board;

procedure Main is

    package IO renames Ada.Text_IO;
    use Board;

    Quit : Boolean := False;
    Current_Player : Board.Player_Type := Board.X;
    Current_Status : Board.Status_Type;

    procedure Next_Player is
    begin
        Current_Player := (case Current_Player is when Board.X => Board.O, when Board.O => Board.X);
    end Next_Player;

    procedure Input is
        User_Input : Character;
    begin
        if Current_Player = Board.X then
            IO.Put ("x>");
        else
            IO.Put ("o>");
        end if;

        IO.Get (User_Input);

        if User_Input = 'q' then
            Quit := True;
        else
            Current_Status := Board.Play (Current_Player, Board.Position_Type'Value ((1 => User_Input)));
        end if;
    end Input;

begin

    Game:
        loop
            Board.Display;
            IO.Put (ASCII.LF);
            Input;

            case Current_Status is
                when Win => Quit := True;
                when Success => Next_Player;
                When Error => IO.Put_Line ("Non playable move. Try again");
            end case;

            exit Game when Quit;
            IO.Put (ASCII.LF);
        end loop Game;

        case Current_Status is
            when Win =>
                if Current_Player = Board.X then
                    IO.Put_Line ("x won! Well done.");
                else
                    IO.Put_Line ("o won! Well done.");
                end if;
            When others => null;
        end case;

end Main;
```

### src/board.ads

```
package Board is

    type Status_Type is (Success, Error, Win);

    type Position_Type is range 1 .. 9;
    type Cell_Type is (None, X, O);
    subtype Player_Type is Cell_Type range X .. O;

    function Is_Playable (Position : in Position_Type) return Boolean;

    function Play 
        (Player :   in Player_Type; 
         Position : in Position_Type)
        return Status_Type;

    procedure Display;

private
    type Grid_Type is array (Position_Type) of Cell_Type;

end Board;
```

### src/board.adb

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

package body Board is
    package IO renames Ada.Text_IO;
    package IIO renames Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

    Grid : Grid_Type := (others => None);

    function Is_Playable ( Position : in Position_Type) return Boolean is
    begin
        return (case Grid (Position) is
            when None => True,
            when others => False);
    end Is_Playable;

    function Play 
        (Player :   in Player_Type; 
         Position : in Position_Type)
        return Status_Type
    is

        function Has_Won return Boolean is
            Col_Count : Integer := 0;
            Row_Count : Integer := 0;
            Diag_Count : Integer := 0;
        begin
            for I in Position_Type range 1 .. 3 loop
                for J in Position_Type range 1 .. 3 loop
                    if Grid ((I - 1) * 3 + J) = Player then
                        Col_Count := Col_Count + 1;
                    end if;

                    if Grid ((J - 1) * 3 + I) = Player then
                        Row_Count := Row_Count + 1;
                    end if;
                end loop;
            end loop;

            if Grid (1) = Player then
                Diag_Count := Diag_Count + 1;
            end if;

            if Grid (5) = Player then
                Diag_Count := Diag_Count + 1;
            end if;

            if Grid (9) = Player then
                Diag_Count := Diag_Count + 1;
            end if;

            return Col_Count = 3 or else Row_Count = 3 or else Diag_Count = 3;
        end Has_Won;

    begin
        if Is_Playable (Position) then
            Grid (Position) := Player;
            return (if Has_Won then Win else Success);
        else
            return Error;
        end if;
    end Play;

    procedure Display is
    begin
        for I in Grid'Range loop
            case Grid (I) is
                when X    => IO.Put (" x ");
                when O    => IO.Put (" o ");
                when None => 
                    IO.Put ("[");
                    IIO.Put (Integer(I), Width => 0);
                    IO.Put ("]");
            end case;

            if I /= 9 and then  I mod 3 = 0 then
                IO.Put (ASCII.LF);
            end if;
        end loop;
    end Display;

end Board;
```

I'm looking for any advices on this code. There is certainly a better "ada way" to do it.